# deallocating memory, static class destructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management

I have a static class I'm using as my data layer in my website. In this class, I have string arrays that store queried information that I can access later. Here's the part of my class and the method in question:

```
public static class data_layer
{
    private static string[] items;
    private static string[] description;

    //will return description for an item id. if no item id is found, null is returned
    public static string getDesc(string key)
    {
        int i = 0;
        bool flag = false;
        //search for the item id to find its index
        for(i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if(items[i] == key)
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag)
            return description[i];
        else
            return null;
    }
    public static string[] getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public static bool setItemsAndDescriptions()
    {
        ArrayList itemIDs = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList itemDescs = new ArrayList();

        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MAS200RAWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT ItemNumber, ItemDescription FROM OUS_IM1_InventoryMasterfile " +
            "WHERE ItemNumber LIKE 'E%' OR ItemNumber LIKE 'B%' OR ItemNumber LIKE 'D%'";

        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
            sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlComm.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader == null)
                return false;

            //add the queried items to the ddl
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                itemIDs.Add(reader["ItemNumber"].ToString().Trim());
                itemDescs.Add(reader["ItemDescription"].ToString().Trim());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();   //NOTE: I HAVE A BREAKPOINT HERE FOR DUBUGGING
        }

        items = itemIDs.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
        description = itemDescs.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
        return true;
    }
}
```

This all works fine, but by putting the breakpoint where I said I put it, I noticed that the class members items and description retain their allocated memory and elements between executions of my program (local asp dev server). Why is this memory not getting released when the program ends (exiting out of the browser or stopping debug mode)? Is there a way to manually release this memory and make a desctructor for a static class?

Comment: by the way, that code is completely non thread-safe (static methods should usually be thread-safe), and the data is slightly at risk of being mutated accidentally by returning `items` out of the class

Comment: I know nothing about threading, really. Recent grad, and never mentioned multithreading in 4yrs of programming major.. uber mad about that

Comment: @Nicklamort - you're writing a **web app**, right? Well, web-servers run multiple threads. So unless you only have 1 user and they promise to only load one page at a time, you should **really** think about thread safety

Comment: It's an offtopic but your code looks awful. Unless you use .NET 1.1, replace ArrayList with its generic version List<T>.
Secondly flag variable is useless. Try refactoring the code.
Also have a look at C# naming convetions, cause it seems you are a Java developper: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Nicklamort welcome to the real world, it won't take you long to realize what you learned at the uni is moderately irrelevant to real software development. Don't get discouraged by dzendras remarks because his statements are what would go through every one of our minds if we reviewed your code. I would recommend taking a look at using Linq2Sql instead of raw ADO.NET for your back end also.

Comment: Some random improvements instead of having items[] and descrptions[], you could use a `Dictionary<string,string>` class and you can do direct key look ups into `var descrption = dict[key]` or checks with `bool itemExists = dict.ContainsKey(key)`

Comment: Chris is right. Don't be encouraged. Treat my comment as a suggestion that is intended to help you make better code. In fact everyone of us wrote the code in the same way you do now, but after a few years you get experienced which makes you see how it should be done. Good luck!

Comment: @dzendras - do you mean "don't be discouraged" ?

Comment: @marc thx, I will def look into thread safety.
@dzendras How will I know if the value was found or not without the flag? And I'll check out List<T>.. still learning basic libraries
@chris yea for sure, my major focused highly on c++, but landed a web dev. pos for 1st job >< so that doesn't help either. I will look into Linq2Sql, I see "LINQ" a lot, must be good.
thx for the advice guys :)

Comment: @dzendras c# has horrible naming conventions. I find lots of the language's built in class names and keyword names very misleading. "static" for example, doesn't mean shared between instances..like most other languages. my names are for my purposes, ill worry about conventioning when my boss bitches at me or I start working with others

Comment: That's not the point. I'm not talking about "how some things are called" rather "how they are formatted".
Have in mind that you use classes from the framework which obey the main naming convetion. Adding your own ("_" inside class names for example) makes your code a terrible mess. Don't expect that someone from the .NET community is keen to make you a codereview or help you write sth as your code is barely readable.

Comment: then say formatting. and as far as i can tell, my formatting is fine

Comment: Class names and methods names should be written in PascalCase and should not have underscores within - it's not PHP.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Your comment wasn't clear before. Yes, I understand this, but that's minor..and completely off topic. I'm sure ppl can read it just fine. I feel sorry for people who assume what something is because of the way the name was "formatted", and long as the name is clear. Unless, of course, that person was collaboratively working on the project, then formatting is expecting, and most often times, communicated beforehand.

Comment: Have fun with that.. got bigger fish to fry bro

Comment: I can see that you're in a good mood. That's fine.
If I can suggest one more thing. Learn how to handle exceptions because the way you made it in this example is totally lame regardless of the naming convetion and even language used.
Have fun with that.

Comment: lol! did you not see from all my other comments, I'M NEW TO c#. I'm not claiming to be GD C# expert. I will learn this when the time comes, it does what I want in the meantime. You can stop bashing on everything to make yourself feel smart, and stick to the topic my question refers to. if you have a suggestion, im open ears to polite delivery such as marc and chris, not rude code bashing. thxbye!

Comment: I tried to convince you to apply to universal C# naming conventions. You didn't agree. OK.

Comment: I accidentally pressed ENTER and couldn't finish my sentence. Now I can see that the chat with you is useless. Stay in your self-admiration. EOT.

Comment: wow.. EOT was 3 comments ago, but go ahead, get the last word in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no such thing as a destructor for a static class, but you can do something like:

```
public static void Unload() {
    items = description = null;
}
```

Re "Why is this memory not getting released when the program ends" - if you mean exiting the browser, the server won't even notice that. It will get cleaned when the app-pool (in IIS) dies.

Comment: Oh, I see. I figured when you exit or browse away from the site, the server would end the app and free all its memory for that user. Thanks, knowing that will def help write my code :)
ps-btw, I'm assuming I would have to call Unload() myself, it wouldn't be automatic like a destructor?

Comment: @Nicklamort - keep in mind that **all** your users are using the **same** static data. Unloading it for user A is also unloading it for user B, and all 14 tabs in 3 browsers by user C

Comment: Marc, if my data is not being cleaned until app-pool dies, would it be possible for a new record to be entered into the database, and a user would try to reload the page, loading a newly sized array into my already defined arrays and throw an error? if so, will setting it to null allow for reallocation?

Comment: Haha, I understand that now that I know it won't be free'd until app-pool dies, thx^^

Answer (score 2):

It's because the fields are static and stopping debugging doesn't mean the WebDev server is shut down.
If you want to store the strings per user, put them in session object. It guarantees that they will be available per user, and will be forgotten once session ends (timeout or closing the browser window).